# How to use CSS grid with a dynamic number of columns and rows?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create a table in Angular with a dynamic number of columns and rows. I've found this easy to accomplish using the HTML table element by doing something like this:

```
    <table class="html-table">
      <tr class="headers">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Sex</th>
        <th *ngIf="columns == 4">Species</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ryan</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td *ngIf="columns == 4">Human</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

In this example there might be some button that toggles the value of `columns` between `3` and `4`.

Every explanation I have looked at online involves changing CSS variables, which seems like a somewhat hacky way to accomplish something that should be simple. Is there some way I can specify that something should be a new column in CSS grid rather than that having to specify the number of columns in `grid-template-columns`?

Comment: Frankly, CSS-Grid is not an ideal replacement for a `table`. Use what works and is *sematically* correct.

Comment: This is one of the few scenarios where I would recommend using a table

Comment: CSS variables is not hacky : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties Maybe not easy to use efficiently, but not hacky since https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/#using-variables , just not finalyzed maybe ;)

Comment: For css-grid what you are asking for is grid-auto-columns: auto; along with grid-auto-flow: column; hope this helps.

Comment: @RudyLister Awesome! Then how do I tell a child element to be a row or a new column?

Comment: may be this will help, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you can use `ng-repeat` to have a dynamic table

A typical example could be

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped">
   <tr ng-repeat="data in datas">
      <td title="Title_Of_First_Variable">{{data.variable1}}</td>
      <td title="Title_Of_Second_Variable">{{data.variable2}}</td>
      <td title="Title_Of_Third_Variable">{{data.variable3}}</td>
      ...
   </tr>
</table>
```

Of course with your controller you should pass your dynamic data into the correct $scope, in this case should be $scope.datas (usually an object)...maybe something like this, using NodeJS:

```
$http.post('route_of_your_method')
.success(function (result) {
     $scope.datas = result;      
})
.error(function (err) {
     ...
});
```

I explained fastly but i hope this is enough